# How to control the order of appearance of markers using leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I'm plotting out markers from GeoJSON files onto my Leaflet map. Some of these markers overlap so now I want to control the order of appearance of these markers so that one type always sits above the others. How do I do this? Is it possible?

The marker that I want to be on top of everything is also moving around in the map  (see url below). I've noticed that sometimes it's above the other markers and sometimes below.

I tried creating layer groups but nothing really happened...?

Here's the map:
http://www.oskarlin.com/hike2013/

Answer (score 5):

Try setting zIndex of `L.Marker` with this [method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setzindexoffset).